# Is there a way to change mesh geometry and/or material dynamically without scaling?

Tags: three.js

I created an object and I want to change dynamically the geometry of that object. the only answer I could find so far was to implement scaling on that object, but it's not what I'm looking for, because it requires constant calculation and it's a bad solution for me. I will be happy to hear any tips and suggestions.

Comment: pls check this https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

Comment: Saw it before, it's not really clear for me what does that mean.

Comment: You can scale the geometry data permanently with [BufferGeometry.scale()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.scale). However, this should be a one time operation since it's way more inefficient than using `Object3D.scale`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scaling is one of the fastest ways to change a geometry, as it only changes one of the parameters already used in the projection calculations. Other generic ways of modifying a geometry will be significantly slower, as every vertex needs to be updated and transferred to the GPU.

Comment: Probably you're right, but anyway I want to know other solutions.